# can't create signalR upload stream from Angular client

Tags: angular, signalr

I have a Angular SPA and want to extend the SignalR connection with a method to stream a file to the server (.Net Core), but my code crashes while calling the connection.send method.

```
const subject: signalR.Subject<number[]> = new signalR.Subject<number[]>();
this.hubConn.send('UploadStream', 'someId', file.name, subject).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

while the hubConn is the connected SignalR connection.

I debugged it down in the HubConnection.js from MS:

```
// We want to iterate over the keys, since the keys are the stream ids
// eslint-disable-next-line guard-for-in
for (const streamId in streams) {
    streams[streamId].subscribe({
        complete: () => {
            ...
```

The values of streamId and streams are as follow:

[image: values of streamId and streams]

**[Edit]**:
after further debugging I noiced the streamId changes to "distinct" right before subscribing:
[image]
[image]

but at the same time it looks like it added an observer...

it actually calls the next and complete methods in the HubConnection.js, the messages go out to the Server, I just have to catch the subscribtion error...

**[/Edit]**

but I get this error:

```
 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: streams[streamId].subscribe is not a function
_launchStreams@http://127.0.0.1:4600/vendor.js:3149:25
send@http://127.0.0.1:4600/vendor.js:2545:10
4770/uploadFile/<@http://127.0.0.1:4600/main.js:4035:24
asyncGeneratorStep@http://127.0.0.1:4600/vendor.js:354268:24
_next@http://127.0.0.1:4600/vendor.js:354290:27
invoke@http://127.0.0.1:4600/polyfills.js:3487:26
onInvoke@http://127.0.0.1:4600/vendor.js:330688:33
invoke@http://127.0.0.1:4600/polyfills.js:3486:52
```

But the Subject I emit has a subscribe function.

I use the latest SignalR npm module: (package.json) `"@microsoft/signalr": "7.0.9"`

Did anyone had such a problem before?
Do I miss something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you share the values of the `stream[]` and `streamId`? I wonder if there is an issue comparing a `number` and a `string`.

Comment: I added them to the post

Comment: Does `streams[3] !== undefined` but `stream['3'] === undefined`?

Comment: as far as I know javascript has no problem accessing an array with a string index
`streams[3]` and `streams['3']` should return the same